# Java parse JSON String to array or objectlist

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm not very familiar with Java, but got the job to reverse the following JSON-Output to a JAVA object-structure:

Sample:

```
{"MS":["FRA",56.12,11.67,"BUY"],"DELL":["MUC",54.76,9.07,"SELL"]}
```

Does someone know, how to build the Arrays / Objetcs and the code to read the strings with Java? JSON or GSON codesamples are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: gson samples can be found (surprise!!!!) in gson source tree -  in unit tests.

Comment: This has nothing to do with reverse-engineering, so I edited the title and removed that tag. Hope you agree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

Type type = new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>(){}.getType();

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map = gson.fromJson( json, type );
```

Where "json" is the json string you defined.

Comment: Now i got it: To read the JSON example test, it is nessecary to delcare the HashMap as <String, Object[]>
Tanks!

Comment: No worries! Don't forget to click the little tick to accept the answer if your happy it solves your issue so the community can benefit ;)

Answer (score 1):

[Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) library is most commonly used to parse JSON in Java. Forget about regular expressions and parsing by hand, this is more complicated than you might think. It all boils down to:

```
String json = "{\"MS\":[\"FRA\",56.12,11.67,\"BUY\"],\"DELL\":[\"MUC\",54.76,9.07,\"SELL\"]}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map obj = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);
```

You can also map directly to Java beans.